# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'random' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery

I have application where i am searching for a particular string.the search result is displayed on the iframe.

there is one page and that page two iframe one below the other.
so search result is in one iframe.on which if we click it will shows the results as details of that record in other iframe.but while displaying the details it gives error as "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'random' of undefined or null reference" and "$ is undefined". i am using jquery 2.1.1.

Comment: Post you code please.

Comment: its difficult to post the code.but can you help with this scenario.

Comment: It's even more difficult to guess what the issue might be without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am having a similar issue and looking for a solution. Facing the problem only on IE 9,10 and 11